# Gmail authentication

Tags: python

I want to make authentication on Gmail, using Grab (Python library).

```
from grab import Grab
g = Grab()
g.go('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1')
g.doc.set_input("Email","*****@gmail.com")
g.doc.set_input("Passwd","*********")
g.doc.submit(submit_name = 'signIn')

print g.doc.select("//title").text()
```

And this code display 'Gmail', but it must print: 'Вхідні - email_name@gmail.com - Gmail', isn`t it?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to automate Gmail logins like this will frequently get tripped up by Google's anti-bot techniques, like captchas.

Gmail has an API you should use instead

- https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview
- https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: So  I never login to Gmail, using Grab? Yes?