# Connection cannot be made using celery and django

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, celery

I learnt how to send email using Django and Celery. I wrote the entire code pretty well. Then when I ran that, I faced an unusual error called

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

- I don't use any firewall or protection system in my system
- I'm new to this so I might even make an error in the command prompt so if there is no error please tell me what to enter correctly in the command prompt too
- I ran the redis server and I feel like it's working pretty fine

This is the entire error I faced

```
-------------- celery@LAPTOP-O88PS3KM v5.2.1 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0 2021-11-18 19:15:24
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         djangocelery:0x2a44256a4c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . djangocelery.celery.debug_task
  . main_app.tasks.test_func
  . send_mail.tasks.user_send_mail

[2021-11-18 19:15:24,519: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
[2021-11-18 19:15:24,525: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-11-18 19:15:25,538: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2021-11-18 19:15:25,546: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\celery\fixups\django.py:203: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory
            leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('''Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory

[2021-11-18 19:15:25,547: INFO/MainProcess] celery@LAPTOP-O88PS3KM ready.
[2021-11-18 19:15:28,285: INFO/MainProcess] Task send_mail.tasks.user_send_mail[1b017ff0-5651-4cf7-b93b-01b77f3a5969] received
[2021-11-18 19:15:28,289: WARNING/MainProcess] xxx@gmail.com
[2021-11-18 19:15:32,371: ERROR/MainProcess] Task send_mail.tasks.user_send_mail[1b017ff0-5651-4cf7-b93b-01b77f3a5969] raised unexpected: ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\projectcelery\send_mail\tasks.py", line 17, in user_send_mail
    send_mail(
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\cepha\Desktop\Web Development\backenddev\Django\django projects\django_with_celery\djangocel\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "C:\Users\cepha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\cepha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\cepha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\cepha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\cepha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
accept_content = ['application/json']
result_serializer = 'json'
task_serializer = 'json'
timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'

result_backend = 'django-db'


CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'



EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'cxxxl.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Celery <xxx.com>'
```

tasks.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from celery import shared_task

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from djangocelery import settings


@shared_task(bind=True)
def user_send_mail(self):
    users = get_user_model().objects.all()

    for user in users:
        mail_subject = "Hi! Celery Testing."
        message = "12345"
        print(user.email)
        to_email = user.email
        send_mail(
            subject=mail_subject,
            message=message,
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=[to_email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    return "Done"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .tasks import test_func
from send_mail.tasks import user_send_mail

# Create your views here.


def test(request):
    test_func.delay()
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Done!</h1>")


def send_mail_to_all(request):
    user_send_mail.delay()
    return HttpResponse("Sent")
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangocelery.settings')

app = Celery('djangocelery')
app.conf.enable_utf = False
# This is used to disable UTC timezone and enable our own one

app.conf.update(timezone="Asia/Kolkata")

app.config_from_object(settings, namespace="CELERY")


# CELERY BEAT SETTINGS

app.conf.beat_schedule = {

}

app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f"Request: {self.request!r}")
```

Comment: Give this answer a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29749831/1637351

Comment: Yeah, I can use that method. But I followed a YouTuber who did that just 2 months ago. For him, it worked perfectly fine. So I thought I had made any minor mistakes